# Python Dataframe for loop issue

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, for-loop

[This is the Example DataFram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ej1e.png)

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNvlc.png)
the above code is working if i manually enter every row, in other terms the function has no error and this code usually generates me a URL

What i am trying to achieve is a for loop which generates me multiple links for each different category ID of the Dataframe and for Each Unique Brand ID generate the URL Using the starting date.

I i want to do is grab the data from the data frame and dynamically input the data from the dataframe.

What i have tried instead is:
[Code i've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKQ2d.png)

Just want to loop through different data and workout my function
Experiencing issues with the syntax, i'm quite not sure how to do it

Comment: Please just post your code here, rather than posting links to images of it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61038370/how-to-put-values-of-pandas-dataframe-into-a-for-loop-in-python