# How to put values of pandas dataframe into a for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

**This is a part of a Python API Connection program**
**Here is the DataFrame Sample**

```
      Region  Sector  Brand ID  Start Date
7188  US      41      40000     2006-03-06
7189  US      41      40345     2017-11-06
7190  US      41      40123     2019-01-12
7191  US      42      40145     2001-02-06
7192  US      42      40185     2013-03-16
```

> Here is the working function as a part of API python program which usually takes a fixed parameter values i.e; Region, Sector, Brand ID, Start Date, End Date="05-04-2020", Scoring ="total".(End Date and Scoring are fixed values, rest of them are keep changing).

```
#This code is working if manually enter
#details of a Dataframe one by one which is inefficient.
#This code generates me a URL of a dataset using the parameters

querySingleBrandTimeline('db.csv', {'region':'us','sector':'41', 'brand_id':'40000', 'scoring':'total', 'start_date':'2006-03-06','end_date':'2020-03-31'})
```

> What I am trying to achieve is a for loop which takes values from the pandas DtaFrame and put it in the function parameters accordingly.

Here is the sample code i've tried:

```
for id in US['Sector']:
  for brandid in US['Brand ID']:
    querySingleBrandTimeline('db.csv', {'region':{}.format(US['Region']),'sector':{}.format(US['Category ID']), 'brand_id':{}.format(US['Brand ID']), 'scoring':'total'}, 'start_date':{}.format{US['Start Date']},'end_date':'2020-03-31'})
```

I'm quite not sure how to pass values of the DataFrame to the function dynamically

Comment: Have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html.

Comment: Can you provide a sample solution rather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the dataframe by rows using iterrows(). I believe your dataframe name is US. Then:

```
for(index, row_data) in US.iterrows():
        querySingleBrandTimeline('db.csv', {'region':{}.format(row_data['Region']),'sector':{}.format(row_data['Category ID']), 'brand_id':{}.format(row_data['Brand ID']), 'scoring':'total'}, 'start_date':{}.format{row_data['Start Date']},'end_date':'2020-03-31'})
```

Comment: Invalid syntax :for(index, US) in US.iterrows():
        querySingleBrandTimeline('db.csv', {'region':{}.format(US['Region']),'sector':{}.format(US['Category ID']), 'brand_id':{}.format(US['Brand ID']), 'scoring':'total'}, 'start_date':{}.format{US['Start Date']},'end_date':'2020-03-31'})

Comment: Not `for(index, US) in US.iterrows()`, it is `for(index, row_data) in US.iterrows()`  and then accessing using `row_data['Region']` etc. @SaiDiwakarBhrugubanda

Answer (score 2):

I think `iterrows` here is not necessary, because slowiest iterate solution in pandas (and output is Series, here are necessary dicts).

First add scalar columns to DataFrame and rename columns names:

```
df1 = df.rename(columns={'Start Date':'start_date'}).rename(columns=str.lower)
df1.insert(3, 'scoring', 'total')
df1['end_date'] = '2020-03-31'
df1['start_date'] = df1['start_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print (df1)
     region  sector  brand id scoring  start_date    end_date
7188     US      41     40000   total  2006-03-06  2020-03-31
7189     US      41     40345   total  2017-11-06  2020-03-31
7190     US      41     40123   total  2019-01-12  2020-03-31
7191     US      42     40145   total  2001-02-06  2020-03-31
7192     US      42     40185   total  2013-03-16  2020-03-31
```

And then convert to list of dicts by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and loop:

```
for d in df1.to_dict('record'):
    print (d)

{'region': 'US', 'sector': 41, 'brand id': 40000, 'scoring': 'total', 'start_date': '2006-03-06', 'end_date': '2020-03-31'}
{'region': 'US', 'sector': 41, 'brand id': 40345, 'scoring': 'total', 'start_date': '2017-11-06', 'end_date': '2020-03-31'}
{'region': 'US', 'sector': 41, 'brand id': 40123, 'scoring': 'total', 'start_date': '2019-01-12', 'end_date': '2020-03-31'}
{'region': 'US', 'sector': 42, 'brand id': 40145, 'scoring': 'total', 'start_date': '2001-02-06', 'end_date': '2020-03-31'}
{'region': 'US', 'sector': 42, 'brand id': 40185, 'scoring': 'total', 'start_date': '2013-03-16', 'end_date': '2020-03-31'}
```

Comment: How do i pass these values to the querySingleBrandTimeline() function.
The list is converting the Time into Timestamp and unable to parse.```{,
  'brand_id': 400000,
  'end_date': '2020-03-31',
  'region': 'US',
  'scoring': 'total',
  'sector': 20,
  'start_date': Timestamp('2018-12-13 00:00:00')}```

Comment: @SaiDiwakarBhrugubanda - Can you add `df1['start_date'] = df1['start_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` before loop?

Comment: In the dataframe , it has the format of (Y,m,d) but when ```dataframe.to_dict('record)``` the format is converting to Timestamp and showing ```'start_date': Timestamp('2018-12-13 00:00:00')```

Comment: @SaiDiwakarBhrugubanda - Yes, understand. Do you try [edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61038471/revisions)?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** [Jezrael's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61038471/6101713) is much better for what you want to do though.

To iterate through a pandas data frame by rows you can use [pandas.DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':[1,5,3,54,34,56,45],
    'col2':['foo','bar','foo','foo','bar','foo','foo'],
    'col3':[True,True,False,True,True,False,True]})

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['col3']:
        print('\n'+str(idx))
        print(row['col2']+'_'+str(row['col1']))
```

Output:

```
0
foo_1

1
bar_5

3
foo_54

4
bar_34

6
foo_45
```